# Why are my Guids being cleared and time being stripped from my DateTime fields in AspnetCore app?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

Net 5.0
I have several fields on a form, two are readonly fields. One is a Guid the other is a DateTime.

When changes are submitted, the Guid is set to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 and the time is removed from my DateTime column 2021-04-13 02:36:37.4567940 becomes 2021-04-13 00:00:00.0000000

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Record.MyGuid" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Record.MyGuid" class="form-control" readonly/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Record.MyGuid" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Record.FormInserted" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Record.FormInserted" class="form-control" readonly/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Record.FormInserted" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

As they appear on the model

```
        [Display(Name="Website ID")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "There should not be a record without an Id. Please report this.")]
        [Editable(false)]
        public Guid MyGuid { get; private set; }

        [Display(Name="Submission date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Submission date is required.")]
        public DateTime FormInserted { get; set; }
```

When the record is retrieved, it has a complete Guid and date. However, when the Post action starts those values are changed even though the form still correctly displays the values.

Here is the Post handler. When I inspect the object Record, the values have been changed when it reaches the `if(Record.Id > 0)` step.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            // At this point, the Guid is now all Zeros
            // and the time has been removed from the DateTimee
            if(Record.Id > 0)
            {
                await _RecordData.Update(Record);
            }
            else
            {
                // No Id means new record. Add it.
                _RecordData.Add(Record);   
            }

            // Commit the changes to the database
            await _RecordData.Commit();
            
            // Message to pass to the details page
            TempData["StatusMessage"] = "Record saved!";
            
            // Redirect to Details page
            return RedirectToPage("./Edit", new { RecordId = Record.MyGuid });
        }
```

What do I need to do to prevent this from happening and preserve the read-only data?

Comment: Hi @sbitaxi,any update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by your model class.

You can change your model like following.

```
    [Display(Name="Website ID")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "There should not be a record without an Id. Please report this.")]
    public Guid MyGuid { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name="Submission date")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Submission date is required.")]
    public DateTime FormInserted { get; set; }
```

Delete the line `[Editable(false)]` and change `DataType.Date` to `DataType.DateTime`.

Besides delete the code `[Editable(false)]`,you also need to delete the code `private`.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed the DataType on my DateTime. That definitely fixes part of it, but the Guid is still being cleared when the post method is initiated.

Comment: Hi @sbitaxi,you can see my updated answer.

Comment: that was exactly it. After I posted my comment, I hacked together something to write back the Id from the page. In order to write to the record I had to remove `private set` and inadvertently fixed the issue.
 `if(Record.MyGuid.ToString() == "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
                {
                    Record.MyGuid = (Guid)recordId;
                }`
I put the code back to private set and confirmed it cleared Guids again. Thank you for the save! I've removed `private` and the unnecessary workaround.